# What are the secrets?

Tags: geometry-dash

At the Geometry Dash icon thingy you will find a star shaped page next to the ball or UFO's. I believe they are called secrets. What are they and what do they do?

Answer (score 2):

This is the "Rainbow Trail".

As you may have already noticed your tail (visible if you go through some sort of boost) will be the same color as your inner color.

The other one will activate the rainbow your tail will be a rainbow.
It will be seen in Ufo, Ball and sShip mode.

Comment: This answer is VERY accurate

Comment: What? No it isn't. The star indicates trails - this refers to a single trail.